# Can't start local Intershop environment because of a invalid certificate in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, intershop

I got a certification error when I start my local environment in Google Chrome. The certificate is not valid. How can I fix this?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to restart the httpd after replacing the server.key and server.crt.

Comment: Good to know this !

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary solution I created a new server certificate with:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt
```

The files server.key and server.crt must be copied to server/local/httpd/conf

Comment: doesn't the server.key get replace with the old files again when you run gradlew deployserver?

Comment: Yes, that is true. A ticket is already open to fix this properly in the standard product.